# Удаление из Set элементов другой коллекции Set

Tags: java, коллекции

В метод передаются две коллекции Set. в Коллекции pets содержатся несколько элементов из cats и их нужно удалить из pets.

Не получается это сделать через итератор, закомментировал реализацию через итератор. Подскажите пожалуйста что я сделал не так.

```
 public static void removeCats(Set<Object> pets, Set<Cat> cats)
 {
//        Iterator<Object> it = pets.iterator();
//
//        for (Cat x : cats) {
//
//            if (x.equals(it)) {
//                it.remove();
//            }
//        }

    for (Cat x : cats)
        pets.remove(x);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял, что и откуда надо удалить, то надо делать так:

```
Iterator iterator = cats.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    pets.remove(iterator.next());
}
```

У вас же зачем-то сравнивается итератор с экземпрялом класса `Cat` и это условие всегда будет `false`, если метод `equals()` реализован верно.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте стандартный метод [removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)):

```
pets.removeAll(cats);
```

При это должны быть корректно переопределены методы `equals` и `hashCode`